# Python grammar: with_stmt

Tags: python, grammar, with-statement

In the [full python grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html) `with` statement is defined as:

```
with_stmt: 'with' with_item (',' with_item)*  ':' suite
with_item: test ['as' expr]
```

Where `expr` is:

```
expr: xor_expr ('|' xor_expr)*
xor_expr: and_expr ('^' and_expr)*
and_expr: shift_expr ('&' shift_expr)*
```

Why does `with_item` contains `expr` rule instead of plain `name`?

This is valid python code:

```
with open('/dev/null') as f:
    pass
```

According to the grammar this code is also valid?

```
with open('/dev/null') as x^y|z:
    pass
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
with open('/dev/null') as x^y|z:
    pass
```

Yes, this code is *valid* according to the grammar! Otherwise you'd get a parse error ("invalid syntax"). The parser proper is fine with this syntax, it's another part of the compiler that checks that such expression is not allowed on the left side (because `as` is semantically equivalent to the assignment). The reason why the grammar allows `expr` here, and not just `NAME` is that you can have any lvalue after `as`:

```
with open('/dev/null') as some.thing
with open('/dev/null') as some[thing]
```

but there's no separate rule for lvalues, e.g. assignments use `testlist` on the left, which is even wider than `expr`.

Comment: +1 Syntactic analysis determines whether the tokens found in the source code form a correct parse tree (as defined by the grammar). Semantic analysis determines whether the resulting parse tree can be evaluated. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler#Front_end)